# String to row conversion SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

How can we convert the following input to a row in SQL Server?

```
'e4lu50', 'e4lu10', 'e4lu11', 'e4de11', 'e4de12', 'e4nl51', 'e4es11'
```

Expected output

```
e4lu50
e4lu10
e4lu11
e4de11
e4de12
e4nl51
e4es11
```

I have a function

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[BreakStringIntoRows] 
     (@CommadelimitedString VARCHAR(1000))  
 RETURNS   
     @Result TABLE (Column1 INT)  
 AS  
 BEGIN  
     DECLARE @IntLocation INT  

     WHILE (CHARINDEX(',', @CommadelimitedString, 0) > 0)  
     BEGIN  
         SET @IntLocation = CHARINDEX(',', @CommadelimitedString, 0)        

         INSERT INTO @Result (Column1)  
             --LTRIM and RTRIM to ensure blank spaces are removed
             SELECT 
                 RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@CommadelimitedString, 0, @IntLocation)))     

             SET @CommadelimitedString = STUFF(@CommadelimitedString, 1, @IntLocation, '')
     END  

     INSERT INTO @Result (Column1)  
         SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(@CommadelimitedString))--LTRIM and RTRIM to ensure blank spaces are removed  

     RETURN   
 END
```

and a query but the problem is its don't take input with a quote

```
WITH SEG(aa) AS
(
    SELECT
        BreakStringIntoRows ('e4lu50', 'e4lu10', 'e4lu11', 'e4de11',
                             'e4de12', 'e4nl51', 'e4es11', 'e4it11')
)
SELECT * 
FROM SEG
```

Comment: use CHOOSE function and try once

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a single string, you have a set of 8 string separated by commas. If you want to stick to your function, then call it as:

```
with SEG(aa) as 
(select BreakStringIntoRows ('e4lu50,e4lu10,e4lu11,e4de11,e4de12,e4nl51,e4es11')
SELECT * from SEG
```

Since you are specifying your string directly in your query, isthat doable? If not, use the REPLACE() function to strip out the quotes before you do your call.

Comment: really appreciate but the issue is we have input in fixed formatt as 'e4lu50,'e4lu10','e4lu11'

Comment: @kirangadhe That is irrelevant. You wrote a function that accepts a single argument. You are not using it correctly. You will need to change the code that is attempting to call your function.

Comment: You must be calling this from somewhere - maybe include the code that calls your sql in the first place. You will just have to change the way your argument(s) are constructed.

Comment: Just to clarify - is this being passed in as a single string with each element quoted? If so then your test query is not emulating this, because it is trying to call your function with 8 separate arguments. To get the same would have to surround the entire sting with single quotes, and convert each internal quot with two quotes. `'''e4lu50'', ''e4lu10'', ''e4lu11'', ''e4de11'', ''e4de12'', ''e4nl51'', ''e4es11'''`